# Display a Dialog in onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WzEvs/286/ I've updated some code so that the Dialog should just be displayed when the button is clicked. But the dialog is not being displayed. Do I need to invoke the module a different way ?

fiddle code :

```
<div ng-app="app" dialog-form=""></div>


<button id="btnSave">Save Click</button>

angular.module("app", []);

  $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnSave").click(
            function () {
                showit();
            }            
        );
    });

function showit(){

    alert('here')

angular.module("app")
    .directive("dialogForm", function () {


    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: "<div id='dialog-form'><label for='name'>Name</label> <input type='text' name='name' id='name' ng-model='data.message'><h1>{{data.message}}</h1></div>",
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.data = {};
            $scope.data.message = "";
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 250,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        element.dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            element.dialog("open");
        }
    };
});
}
```

Update :

Here is what I've tried in order to display this as a ng-click but nothing gets fired :

http://jsfiddle.net/WzEvs/300/

Code :

```
<table>
    <tr ng-controller="MyController" ng-click="showit()">Click</tr>
</table>

function MyController($scope) {

$scope.showit() = function() {

    alert('here')

angular.module("app")
    .directive("dialogForm", function () {


    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: "<div id='dialog-form'><label for='name'>Name</label> <input type='text' name='name' id='name' ng-model='data.message'><h1>{{data.message}}</h1></div>",
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.data = {};
            $scope.data.message = "";
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 250,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        element.dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            element.dialog("open");
        }
    };
});
};
```

What should display : ok alert box "here". When click "ok" a new Dialog (called dialogForm) in above code.

What is displayed : ok alter box "here". When click "ok" the ok box disappears but the new Dialog (called dialogForm) in above code is not displayed.

Update :

accepted answer code :

html :

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div dialog-form=""></div>
    <button id="btnSave">Save Click</button>
</div>
```

javascript :

```
angular.module("app", []);

angular.module("app")
.directive("dialogForm", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: "<div id='dialog-form'><label for='name'>Name</label> <input type='text' name='name' id='name' ng-model='data.message'><h1>{{data.message}}</h1></div>",
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.data = {};
            $scope.data.message = "";
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 250,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        element.dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

                        angular.element("#btnSave").on("click", function () {
                element.dialog("open");
            });
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: have you considered using ng-click?

Comment: your jsfiddle worked fine for me in all 3 major browsers (Firefox 26.0, IE 10, Chrome 35.0).  When I click "Save Click" button a dialog pops up with "here", message.  although, all 3 had different styles of displaying the dialog box.

Comment: @CodeCowboyOrg yes but the dialog itself is not displayed ?

Comment: @Daniel A. White yes, just now. ive updated question

Comment: @blue-sky, it displays for me in all 3 browsers.  What do you mean by not "displayed"?  That nothing happens?  There is a "here" dialog displayed in all 3 browsers for me.  Which Browser and Version are you using?

Comment: @CodeCowboyOrg ive updated question. a jQuery dialog should display after the "ok" popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the directive link function by selecting the button to trigger your dialog to open:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div dialog-form=""></div>
    <button id="btnSave">Save Click</button>
</div>

angular.module("app")
.directive("dialogForm", function () {

return {
    restrict: "A",
    template: "<div id='dialog-form'><label for='name'>Name</label> <input type='text' name='name' id='name' ng-model='data.message'><h1>{{data.message}}</h1></div>",
    controller: function ($scope, $element) {
        $scope.data = {};
        $scope.data.message = "";
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 250,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    element.dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        // From the dialog-form element, find the "#btnSave" sibling element.
        // bind the dialog open function to a click event on that element.

        element.siblings("#btnSave").on("click", function() {
            element.dialog("open");
        });
    }
};

});
```

Optionally you can use angular.element() in the directive's link function to avoid worrying about the placement of the button (id selectors are the fastest anyway).

```
angular.element("#btnSave").on("click", function(){ element.dialog("open"); });
```

Comment: can you add this to a fiddle, ive tried http://jsfiddle.net/WzEvs/304/ but does not seem to work ?